# Why FIRST_VALUE and EXISTS statement in WHERE clause doesn't filter rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

In the output of the below sample I would expect to see a single row with ControlNo = 2222.

But why it still brings me 2 rows?

**TEST data**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pol') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #pol;
select 1111 as ControlNo, 'Policy1' as PolicyNumber, 'Cancelled' as CurrStatus, 0 as Premium
into #pol
union 
select 2222 as ControlNo, 'Policy1' as PolicyNumber, 'Bound' as CurrStatus, 100 as Premium
--select * from #pol

select *
from #pol a
where PolicyNumber = 'Policy1'
-- here I want to filter only  ControlNo 2222
and exists(
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ControlNo) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) 
FROM #pol p
WHERE p.ControlNo = a.ControlNo
)
```

Otput:

```
ControlNo   PolicyNumber    CurrStatus  Premium
  1111     Policy1          Cancelled     0
  2222     Policy1           Bound       100
```

If I run just FIRST_VALUE statement then it works as expected. Gave me the last `ControlNo`, which is 2222.

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ControlNo) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) 
FROM #pol p

(No column name)
    2222
    2222
```

But if I place this statement in EXISTS clause then it brings me both `ControlNo`'s

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE` in an `EXISTS` is pointless as all that matters is if any rows are returned in an `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Your EXISTS subquery will evaluate as true for every non-null value of ControlNo. That's because the WHERE clause gets evaluated before FRIST_VALUE() and also because your subquery is partitioned on PolicyNumber but not correlated on PolicyNumber. Try one of the following to see the difference:

```
SELECT ControlNo, PolicyNumber, CurrStatus, Premium
FROM
(
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ControlNo) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) AS FirstControlNo, *
FROM #pol
) AS p
WHERE ControlNo = FirstControlNo;


SELECT ControlNo, PolicyNumber, CurrStatus, Premium
FROM #pol AS p
WHERE ControlNo = (SELECT MAX(q.ControlNo) FROM #pol AS q WHERE q.PolicyNumber = p.PolicyNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 rows because for both values of `a.ControlNo` (1111 and 2222) that you use in join, `EXISTS` query gives back a result. So both are valid:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ControlNo) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) 
FROM #pol p
WHERE p.ControlNo = 1111 -- Exists

SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ControlNo) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) 
FROM #pol p
WHERE p.ControlNo = 2222 -- Exists
```

Therefore both `1111` and `2222` rows pass the criteria.

If you just want to take out latest entry per PolicyNumber this is correct way to do it:

```
;WITH ControlNoPerPolicyDescCTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY ControlNo DESC) AS RowNumber,
        p.ControlNo,
        p.PolicyNumber,
        p.CurrStatus,
        p.Premium
    FROM #pol p
)
SELECT cpd.ControlNo,
       cpd.PolicyNumber,
       cpd.CurrStatus,
       cpd.Premium
FROM ControlNoPerPolicyDescCTE AS cpd
WHERE cpd.RowNumber = 1
```

Mark each row by a `ROW_NUMBER` from `1` to `n`, for each `PolicyNumber` (in our case desending) and select only rows with `ROW_NUMBER = 1`.